# SpriteKit - Creating Changing Gradients

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gradient, cifilter

Currently I am creating a gradient using `CIFilter`. Code:

```
//In update function

let context = CIContext(options: nil)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
let startVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: 0)
let endVector = CIVector(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height)
let color1 = CIColor(red: red1/255, green: green1/255, blue: blue1/255, alpha: 1)
let color2 = CIColor(red: red2/255, green: green2/255, blue: blue2/255, alpha: 1)

//Here I would change all rgb values by +- 0.2 - 0.5

filter!.setDefaults()

filter!.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
filter!.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
filter!.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
filter!.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")

let image = context.createCGImage(filter!.outputImage!, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
let texture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(cgImage: image!))
backgroundImage.texture = texture
```

My goal is to create a background gradient that changes color. When I tried to do this using `CIFilter`, it worked, but my CPU jumped up to 100%, much higher than my usual 20%.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

If the color of the gradients are needed:

[image: Start]
[image: Destination]

Comment: There's a few ways to do this much more efficiently, but each has limitations. Is there someway you can show the types of gradients you want to make, and how you want them to transition from one to another?

Comment: @Confused I just want to make a linear gradient from top to bottom, that changes color (The top may go from red to green and the bottom from blue to yellow, creating a changing gradient.)

Comment: Again, sorry, I need to see what you think is the first gradient, and the destination gradient. I can't help without a visual exactitude of these things. There are MANY ways to make gradients, and there are many more types of gradients.

Comment: @Confused I'm not quite sure what you're asking for, but I'll try my best to answer: The first gradient will be linear with the top color beginning at the top of the screen, and the bottom color at the bottom. The second will be exactly the same, except with different colors. I don't see any other information that would be of use...

Comment: I want to see images of the desired gradients. It's precisely because only you can currently conceive of how your gradients look that I'd like to see them. There's (literally) unlimited ways to create gradients between colours... can you create them, or show me images of other gradients you've found somewhere online that match what you're starting with, and ending with? Then we can talk about the similarly numerous ways to blend/animate between them.

Comment: @Confused I added images to the question

Answer (score 0):

I found this very good git that has a lot of functionality. This should help you out.

https://github.com/braindrizzlestudio/BDGradientNode